# Airflow DockerOperator Dynamic docker_url passing

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

Airflow Docker operator Docker url dynamic config.

we want to pass the run time conf to docker_url.

docker operator code

```
end = DockerOperator(
task_id='docker_command_sleep',
container_name="{{dag_run.conf.get('ip', '') if dag_run}}",
image='nginx',
api_version='auto',
auto_remove=True,
docker_url="{{dag_run.conf.get('ip', '') if dag_run}}"
```

run_config

```
{"ip":"tcp://1.1.1.1:2375"}
```

error we are getting
docker.errors.DockerException: Invalid bind address format: port is required:

```
{"ip":"tcp://1.1.1.1:2375"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `docker_url` parameter is [not a templated field for the DockerOperator](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/4298c433bc8b3136b8131ebe006dcf10c601e9c1/airflow/providers/docker/operators/docker.py#L183). Only templated fields can accept a Jinja expression (you can learn more [here](https://docs.astronomer.io/learn/templating)).

However, you can subclass the DockerOperator, add `docker_url` as a templated field, and then use the subclassed version of the operator in your DAG(s).

```py
from airflow.providers.docker.operators.docker import DockerOperator


class MyDockerOperator(DockerOperator):
    template_fields = (*DockerOperator.template_fields, "docker_url")
```